# How to generate Rownumber for records in SSRS when using RowVisibility based on a condition

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using SQL 2008 R2. I want to generete row number for the records. I can use expression `RowNumber(Nothing)`

But the rowvisibilty property is set to true based on the condition specified. My Row numbers are not correct.

How do I generate correct row numbers when using rowvisibility?. I am using SP List data so filtering has bit problem as my filter condition takes a complex condition.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to amend the selection criteria so that the suppressed rows aren't selected.

Failing that, try sorting the data so that the suppressed rows are at the end of the dataset and therefore do not affect the row numbers of the visible rows.